# getting nil value while calling api (alamofire)

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, ios9, alamofire

i am using alamofire to call api. but in this particular api i am getting nil value as a response. actually when i hit my api in my browser its working pretty well.

here is my code

```
 func web()
{


    request(.GET, "http://www.horecasupply.nl/AJAX?function=appStructure", parameters: nil, encoding: .JSON).responseJSON { (response : Response<AnyObject, NSError>) -> Void in
        if response.result.value != nil {
            print(response.result.value)
        }

    }

}
```

getting nil value and when i print respose its showing me

```
Printing description of response.result.Failure:
Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "Invalid value around character 1."         
UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=Invalid value around character 1.}
```

EDIT 1:: tried responsestring instead of responsejson. 
but getting different kind of response so how can i convert it?

> \r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n</script>\r\n DD_belatedPNG.fix(\'img, .png_bg\'); //fix any  or .png_bg background-images </script>\r\n\r\n\r\n</script>\r\n</script>-->\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n  \r\n\r\n")

Comment: Try using `responseString` instead of `responseJson` [Alamofire invalid value around character 0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32355850/alamofire-invalid-value-around-character-0)

Comment: by using responsestring getting this kind of response \r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n</script>\r\n DD_belatedPNG.fix(\'img, .png_bg\'); //fix any or .png_bg background-images </script>\r\n\r\n\r\n</script>\r\n</script>-->\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n \r\n\r\n")

Comment: I ran the same code u have posted & it works properly .I m getting same response as of browser.

Comment: which xcode are you using ? poojathorat

Comment: Your code snippet works for me ([screenshot](https://www.evernote.com/l/AOwYaIzaSFZEebo3JmdJu5zWCCXIMc_GUPE)).

Comment: have you changed anything in your info.plist?? @EricD.

Comment: Just added ["Allow arbitrary loads"](https://www.evernote.com/l/AOzc6LuWYLtE4ZcShiuwIJxzJe9FsQdRpxI) but nothing special other than that.

Comment: its really annoying same code not working for me. in response after getting data in number format i am getting this.  result : FAILURE: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "Invalid value around character 1." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=Invalid value around character 1.

Comment: hi @EricD. is there any other solution?

Answer (score -2):

Give this code a shot, this should work:

```
    Alamofire.request(.GET, "http://www.horecasupply.nl/AJAX?function=appStructure").responseJSON { response in
    if response.result.value != nil {
        print(response.result.value)
    }
}
```

Comment: Why? How? OP's code worked for me, why do you think replacing it by yours would improve their situation? Please explain your answer.