# Pass integers is failing in Alamofire POST request ( Json Serilization error)

Tags: iphone, json, swift, swift3, alamofire

```
 let parameters : [ String : Any] = [
            "test_id": 1,
            "std_id": 1,
            "d_mins": 10
        ]

       Alamofire.request("http://cloud.com/xxx",method: .post,parameters: parameters,encoding: JSONEncoding.default,headers: headers).responseJSON { response in
            print(response)
            print(response.result)
           print(response.result.isSuccess)
        }

    }
```

Facing below error

Notifying 
FAILURE: responseSerializationFailed(Alamofire.AFError.ResponseSerializationFailureReason.jsonSerializationFailed(Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "No value." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=No value.}))
FAILURE
false

[image]

Comment: I think if you watch the request with something like [Charles](http://charlesproxy.com) or [Wireshark](http://wireshark.org), I bet you'll see a well-formed JSON request. The problem may well rest in the server code (or some disconnect between what the client is sending and what the server was expecting). Are you sure it's expecting numeric values and not string values? Are you sure your server can handle the JSON request and is not, for example, expecting a `x-www-form-urlencoded` request? Are you sure the keys are right?

Comment: @MücahitTekin tried no luck :(

Comment: @Rob i tried   let body: Parameters = [
            "institute_id": 1,
            "student_id": 1,
            "delayed_mins": 10
        ] , tried the same thing from POSTMAN client it works with json like below {"institute_id":1,"student_id":1,"delayed_mins":10} it works ..

Comment: Maybe this helps http://stackoverflow.com/a/33541493/1877810

Comment: What is the `statusCode` of the response? I might add a `validate()` call before the `responseJSON` and make sure you're getting a 200 response code. See [Response Validation](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire#response-validation).

Comment: tried  Alamofire.request("http://cloud.com/xxx",method: .post,parameters: parameters,encoding: JSONEncoding.default,headers: headers)
         .validate(statusCode: 200..<300)
        .responseJSON { response in
        
        
        print(response)
            print(response.result)
           print(response.result.isSuccess) }   No luck

Comment: @Mücahit Tekin  u saved my day, changing to responseJson worked .. :)

Comment: @Badrinath great that worked :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Alamofire invalid value around character 0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32355850/alamofire-invalid-value-around-character-0)