# why I am getting this error , responseSerializationFailed?

Tags: ios, json, swift, alamofire, jsonserializer

Here is my code

```
        Alamofire.request(URL, method: requestType, parameters: param, encoding: URLEncoding.default, headers: headers).responseJSON { (response:DataResponse<Any>) in


        switch(response.result) {
        case .success(_):
            if response.result.value != nil{


                completion(response.result.value!)
            }
            break

        case .failure(_):
            print(response.result.error!)
            failure(response.result.error!)
            break

        }
    }
```

> responseSerializationFailed(Alamofire.AFError.ResponseSerializationFailureReason.jsonSerializationFailed(Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "Invalid value around character 0." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=Invalid value around character 0.}))
>   Could not cast value of type 'Alamofire.AFError' (0x100969000) to 'Swift.Array<__ObjC.NSDictionary>' (0x174094340).
>   2017-11-29 16:01:09.744776 WTV_GO[2333:1690232] Could not cast value of type 'Alamofire.AFError' (0x100969000) to 'Swift.Array<__ObjC.NSDictionary>' (0x174094340).

I got this error when putting firebase token and other parameters to the server but same parameters works fine through Postman, is there any solution?
Thank you!

Comment: post your code here

Comment: @JitendraModi see my sample with requestType is put, can you provide any solution for this type of error.

Comment: Have you tried changing `encoding: URLEncoding.default` to `encoding: JSONEncoding.default` ?

Comment: You are getting an invalid response that it cannot parse. check your response and use something like jsonlint.com to verify it

Comment: @JitendraModi still getting same error  by using `encoding: JSONEncoding.default`

Comment: what is your request type ? @PurushottamPadhya Try with requestType 'get'

Comment: @JitendraModi request type is put and included provided some parameter.

Comment: @PurushottamPadhya change `.responseJSON` to `.responseString` refer link https://stackoverflow.com/q/32355850/5523205

Answer (score 1):

**Finally, solved this problem**. I have changed code to `encoding: URLEncoding.queryString` from `encoding: URLEncoding.default`

Answer (score 0):

As per your error looks like you have not handle error.
Please look at follow sample code to handle `success` response result and `error` response result.

```
    Alamofire.request(url, method: .post, parameters: parameters, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: nil) .responseJSON { response in
                    switch response.result {
                    case .success(_):
                        print(response)
                        // Do your stuff here
                    case .failure(_):

                        print("Request failed with error: \(response.result.error ?? "" as! Error)")
                        //handle error here
                    }
```

Comment: I am implementing all the error handling code, you can see above my code with requestType is put.

Comment: Yes, you have added your code now in question. will look