# Cannot update data in API using .PUT request in Alamofire

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire, put

I am creating an Event app where in the user should tap **Check In Button** to register for the event. `registered_flag : false` will be `true` and `registered_type: 0` will be `1` once the user tapped the button. But as I build and run the app, error appeared that says

> responseSerializationFailed(Alamofire.AFError.ResponseSerializationFailureReason.jsonSerializationFailed(Error
>   Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "Invalid value around character
>   0." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=Invalid value around character 0.})).

I am not really confident regarding the content of my codes in my APIService. Hope someone will help me to correct my codes so I could build and run my app successfully. Thank you so much.

**application/json that needs to be updated which inside event_participant**

```
{
   "registered_flag": false,
    "registration_type": 0
}
```

**event_participant**

```
"event_participants": [
    {
        "participant_id": "70984656-92bc-4c36-9314-2c741f068523",
        "employee_number": null,
        "last_name": "Surname",
        "first_name": "FirstName",
        "middle_name": null,
        "display_name": "Surname, FirstName ",
        "department_name": "Department",
        "position_name": "Developer",
        "registered_flag": false,
        "registered_datetime": "2018-09-13T08:54:40.150",
        "registration_type": 0,
        "delete_flag": false,
        "manual_reg_flag": false,
        "out_flag": false,
        "out_datetime": null,
        "classification": 6,
        "others": "Guest"
      }
    }
```

**API Service using PUT request in Alamofire**

```
func updateParticipant(updateType: UpdateParticipantType,
                       participantID: String,
                       completionHandler: @escaping(([Attendee]?, Error?) -> Void)) {

    let updateParticipantURL = URL(string: "\(REGISTER_PARTICIPANT_URL)/\(updateType)/\(participantID)")

    let headers: HTTPHeaders = [
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
    ]

    let parameters: Parameters = [
        "registered_flag": false,
        "registration_type": 0
    ]

    Alamofire.request(updateParticipantURL!, method: .put, parameters: parameters, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: headers).responseJSON { (response) in

        switch response.result {
        case .success:
            print("Done")

            if let jsonArray = response.result.value as? [[String : Any]] {
                for anItem in jsonArray {
                    if let eventparticipant = anItem["event_participants"] as? [[String : Any]] {
                        var extractedAttendee = [Attendee]()
                        for participant in eventparticipant{
                            print(participant)
                            let success = Attendee.init(JSON: participant)
                            extractedAttendee.append(success!)
                        }
                        completionHandler(extractedAttendee, nil)
                    }
                }
            }

        case .failure(let error):
            completionHandler(nil, error)
        }
    }
}
```

**Struct for Attendee**

```
struct Attendee: Decodable {

let id: String
let employeeNumber: String?
let lastName: String
let firstName: String
let middleName: String
let displayName: String
let department: String
let position: String
let registeredFlag: Bool
let registeredDateTime: Date?
let registrationType: Int
let deleteFlag: Bool
let manualFlag: Bool
let outFlag: Bool
let outDateTime: Date?
let classification: Int?
let others: String?
```

[postman response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YiKgB.png)

Comment: Are you able to call your service through postman?

Comment: Are you getting the success of request?

Comment: try to make call using `encoding: URLEncoding = URLEncoding.httpBody`. Hope this will help you.

Comment: @bestiosdeveloper yes I did that

Comment: @JogendarChoudhary response is failed

Comment: What is the type of value that your API service accepts? for 
 `registered_flag` and `registration_type`. Is it boolean or number as mentioned? Can you check once and confirm

Comment: @SahebRoy is right, once check that. And please try making a call on postman first, is it working on postman or not?

Comment: @SahebRoy `registered_flag : Bool` and `registration_type: Int`. I edited my question and I added the `Attendee` struct

Comment: What is the response of u try to use a rest client with the exact same response?

Comment: @bestiosdeveloper I tried it using postman and it worked. I add an image of my postman above for you reference.

Comment: @bestiosdeveloper https://i.stack.imgur.com/YiKgB.png

Comment: I got `200 Ok` in postman but in network response in swift I got `failure`

Comment: @Titus but it's not working at my end. Showing : "message": "The requested resource does not support http method 'GET'."

Comment: There are other answers around this issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32355850/alamofire-invalid-value-around-character-0

Comment: @bestiosdeveloper have you check my postman image?

Comment: @Titus Yes, I've.

Comment: @Titus When I'm trying to make call it's showing: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7T2Up.png
And I think it's getting called.

Comment: @bestiosdeveloper still no working for me. Still can't figure it out which part of my code is wrong

Comment: Brain dead in this issue, Still can't resolve my issue, please help me. Thank you