# How can I pull the grades on the website, and perform the login using a POST request?

Tags: ios, swift, httprequest

I am trying to pull my school grades from the website which stores all my grades, but I am having trouble logging in using HTTP requests, and pulling the information of the next page. Any help is appreciated :)

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let myUrl = NSURL(string: "https://homeaccess.katyisd.org/HomeAccess/Account/LogOn?ReturnUrl=%2fhomeaccess%2f")
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: myUrl!)
    request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
    let postString = "User_Name=**hidden**&Password=**hidden**"
    request.HTTPBody = postString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
    let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request){
        data,response,error in
        if(error != nil){
            print("error=\(error)")
            return
        }

        print("response = \(response)")

        // Print out response body
        let responseString = NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
        print("responseString = \(responseString)")

        //Let’s convert response sent from a server side script to a NSDictionary object:

        do{
        var myJSON = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: .MutableLeaves) as? NSDictionary

        if let parseJSON = myJSON {
            // Now we can access value of First Name by its key
            var firstNameValue = parseJSON["User_Name"] as? String
            print("firstNameValue: \(firstNameValue)")
        }


        }catch{
            print(error)
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: without login data it is hard to tell whats going wrong... is anything going wrong at all? what error do you get? what is going wrong? what problems do you exactly have?

Comment: Nothing gets printed inside the console

Comment: ok. this makes sense since you do not fire the request at all. add `task.resume()` at the end of your code...

Comment: This is the error I get http://puu.sh/o54ml/9875726fc2.png

Comment: Advice, move your server code outside of your VC

Answer (score 0):

1. First, you need `task.resume()` after defining the task in order to start the connection loading, otherwise the object will be created and nothing will actually happen.
2. According to [this error you posted](http://puu.sh/o54ml/9875726fc2.png), there's an SSL verification error on the site you are trying to access. The most secure option is to fix the SSL on the site, but I presume that is beyond your control in this case. The easier fix is to bypass the SSL error by adding `"App Transport Security Settings" > "Allow Arbitrary Loads" = YES` in your `info.plist`, as @André suggested. Or, if you are only using the one domain, bypass the particular domain in the `NSExceptionDomains`. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31080818/what-is-the-best-practice-to-parse-html-in-swift) for more info.
3. According to [this error you posted](http://puu.sh/o551X/87214a65bf.png), a JSON parsing error is occurring. It is currently being caught and printed by your catch block, so the data is not actually processed. In your case, this is occurring because the response from Home Access Center is HTML, not JSON, so the JSON parser is failing. You are probably looking for an **HTML parser**. Swift does not have one built-in; look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31080818/what-is-the-best-practice-to-parse-html-in-swift) for some example open-source options.

I have actually created a program that interfaces with Home Access Center. Sadly, there is no public API available -- APIs typically return JSON, which is easier to work with. Instead, you will need to use an HTML parser to analyze the page that is meant for human users and cookies to fake that a human user is logging on.

Comment: #2 - Do not make those changes to the Info.plist. It is not appropriate to allow all arbitrary loads to fix one specific issue.

Comment: @rmaddy True, I modified by answer to specify that it's not the best way but the easiest way. I am also presuming he cannot access the domain itself and fix the SSL problem at the source.

Comment: @BradzTech I know this is a very old question, but I'm trying to find info about Home Access Center.  I can't find the company that publishes HAC.  I'm look for options to integrate with HAC in our school district.

Answer (score -1):

add `task.resume()` at the end of your code. also add the following to your `info.plist` file:

[image: info.plist]

Comment: yeah, looks like you can't make the post request like you try to. i get a status 500 (internal server error)...

Comment: ask your IT department if it's possible for you to use any kind of API to get your grades... :)

Comment: Could I use an invisible UIWebview, and just pull the html stuff form the page after login?

Comment: Do not make those changes to the Info.plist. It is not appropriate to allow all arbitrary loads to fix one specific issue.

Comment: @rmaddy since he did not really use what request to make, which url to use and if it works at all in this case it was the easiest solution for testing purposes. of course that's not a final solution...

Comment: But you posted it as the solution. It's bad advice as written.