# Read DIV from string

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

**I need to read a specific HTML of a div that is loaded in a webview**

```
doc = web.stringByEvaluatingJavaScript(from: "document.body.innerHTML")!
```

**With the above code I get the HTML in the webview and turn it into a string**

**Now I'm trying to get a particular div that HTML**

```
<div id="status_load" name="status_load">DESLIGADO</div><p>Luz <a href="?pin=LIGADO"><button>Ligar</button></a>&nbsp;<a href="?pin=DESLIGADO"><button>Desligar</button></a></p>
```

**I tried to do so, but do not return anything!**

```
web.stringByEvaluatingJavaScript(from: "document.getElementById('status_load').value")!
```

**Does anyone know how to do this?**

Comment: divs don't have values. `.value` is for form `<input>` tags.

Comment: of the same, does not return anything

Comment: I think what you need is an HTML parser. Take a look at this discussion for an overview of what is available: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31080818/what-is-the-best-practice-to-parse-html-in-swift