# Parsing html in swift with Kanna

Tags: html, swift, parsing, xpath

I'm trying to parse a html into my swift project using Kanna, I used this [What is the best practice to parse html in swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31080818/what-is-the-best-practice-to-parse-html-in-swift), as a guide.

This is the code I'm using to parse the html:

```
if let doc = Kanna.HTML(html: myHTMLString, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8) {
    var bodyNode = doc.body

    if let inputNodes = bodyNode?.xpath("//a/@href[ends-with(.,'.txt')]") {
        for node in inputNodes {
            print(node.content)
        }
    }
}
```

Now I dont have any experince with this, but I believe that I have to change the `.xpath("//a/@href[ends-with(.,'.txt')]")` to get the specific information I need.

This is the html im trying to parse:

view-source:https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_inorganic_compounds

What I want from this line is the title: "Aluminium antimonide" and the chemical formular: "AlSb".

[image]

Can anybody tell me what to write in the `.xpath(...)`, or maybe explain to me how it works?

Answer (score 1):

> Swift 3

To get all items with a loop

```
for item in doc.xpath("//div[@class='mw-content-ltr']/ul/li") {
    print(item.at_xpath("a")?["title"])
    print(item.text) // this returns the whole text, you may need further actions here
}
```

Or to access a specific item

```
print(doc.xpath("//div[@class='mw-content-ltr']/ul/li")[0].at_xpath("a")?["title"])
print(doc.xpath("//div[@class='mw-content-ltr']/ul/li")[0].text)
```

You can check xpath tutorials and docs for more.