# How to get only link from this string?

Tags: regex, swift

I want to get only the link from this string:

```
"<p><a href=\"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i2yscjyIBsk\">https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i2yscjyIBsk</a></p>\n"
```

I want output as `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i2yscjyIBsk`

So, how I can I achieve it?

I have tried:

```
func matches(for regex: String, in text: String) -> [String] {
do {
let regex = try NSRegularExpression(pattern: regex)
let nsString = text as NSString
    let results = regex.matches(in: text, range: NSRange(location: 0, length: nsString.length))
    return results.map { nsString.substring(with: $0.range)}
} catch let error {    
}
```

And tried this regex: `"<a[^>]+href=\"(.*?)\"[^>]*>.*?</a>"`

But still I can't figure it out.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the best practice to parse html in swift?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31080818/what-is-the-best-practice-to-parse-html-in-swift)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

By using `NSDataDetector` class you can extract links exactly:

```
let text = "<p><a href=\"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i2yscjyIBsk\">https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i2yscjyIBsk</a></p>\n"
let types: NSTextCheckingType = .Link
let detector = try? NSDataDetector(types: types.rawValue)

guard let detect = detector else {
    return
}

let matches = detect.matchesInString(text, options: .ReportCompletion, range: NSMakeRange(0, text.characters.count))

for match in matches {
    print(match.URL!)
}
```

**Description:**  *`NSDataDetector` class can match dates, addresses, links, phone numbers and transit information. [Reference](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsdatadetector).*

*The results of matching content is returned as `NSTextCheckingResult` objects. However, the `NSTextCheckingResult` objects returned by `NSDataDetector` are different from those returned by the base class `NSRegularExpression`.*

*Results returned by `NSDataDetector` will be of one of the data detectors types, depending on the type of result being returned, and they will have corresponding properties. For example, results of type date have a date, `timeZone`, and duration; results of type link have a `url`, and so forth.*

---

There is another way to get link and other specific string between `<a> ... </a>` tag:

```
let string = "<p><a href=\"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i2yscjyIBsk\">https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i2yscjyIBsk</a></p>\n"
let str = string.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("<[^>]+>", withString: "", options: .RegularExpressionSearch, range: nil)
print("string: \(str)")
```

Output:

```
string: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i2yscjyIBsk
```

**Note:** *I suggest you to use above solution to get the links specifically thanks.*

Comment: Just note that this does not extract the link target (the href in the anchor) but the *text* between `<a ..>` and `</a>`. That text need not be a link and need not be equal to the href.

Comment: @MartinR i respect your correct explanation here, i found this working solution in my case also that's why i suggested. Can you please elaborate more this `That text need not be a link and need not be equal to the href` so i do update me and suggestion both :)

Comment: What I meant is that for `let string = "<p><a href=\"https://www.google.com\">What??</a></p>\n"` your code will extract `What??` and not `https://www.google.com`.

Comment: okay now understood what you meant `<a> ... </a>`, i will search for the better solution and it will be nice that you could provide some links thanks very much :)