# How to parse a specific tag in swift

Tags: swift, html-parsing

I have this line of code in my HTML page: `<a href="www.myWebsite.com" rel="ibox"></a>`.

How can I parse it in swift code in the best way, considering that I have not only this tag "a" but many?

Comment: did you try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31080818/what-is-the-best-practice-to-parse-html-in-swift

Answer (score 2):

Parsing HTML in Swift typically requires a third-party framework, personally, I use [SwiftSoup](https://github.com/scinfu/SwiftSoup).

Here's how you would parse that `href` in Swift using SwiftSoup.

```
do {
   let html = "<a href=\"www.myWebsite.com\" rel=\"ibox\"></a>"
   let doc: Document = try SwiftSoup.parse(html)
   let links = try doc.select("a").map {
        try $0.attr("href")
    } // ["www.myWebsite.com"]
} catch Exception.Error(let type, let message) {
    print(message)
} catch {
    print("error")
}
```

[Link to the documentation](https://github.com/scinfu/SwiftSoup#to-parse-an-html-document)

In the above, the `links` array holds the values of *all* the links on a page.

Comment: And if I want to retrieve the string that is in the href attribute? (So in this case "www.myWebSite.com")

Comment: That is what the above does, on line 5

Answer (score 2):

```
import Foundation

let html = "theHtmlYouWannaParse"

var err : NSError?
var parser     = HTMLParser(html: html, error: &err)
if err != nil {
    println(err)
    exit(1)
}

var bodyNode   = parser.body

if let inputNodes = bodyNode?.findChildTags("b") {
    for node in inputNodes {
        println(node.contents)
    }
}

if let inputNodes = bodyNode?.findChildTags("a") {
    for node in inputNodes {
        println(node.getAttributeNamed("href")) //<- Here you would get your files link
    }
}
```

Comment: But I only want to retrieve the link "www.myWebsite.com" and not also the others

Comment: let html = "<a href="www.myWebsite.com" rel="ibox"></a>."

Comment: Maybe I have written the question bad. I want to retrieve the string in the href, but I don't know what is in. I only know that is <a> tag and that has attribute rel="ibox"