# htmlDocPtr/gethtml issue

Tags: ios, xcode, html-parsing, libxml2

I have this kind of code in an iOS app of mine:

```
NSString *docNameString;
docNameString=@"https://www.mysite.php";
documentHTML=gethtml((char*)[docNameString UTF8String],
                     (char*)[@"UTF-8" UTF8String]);
```

It was working up to now (meaning last time I touched the app in Xcode).

But now it is no longer working. I get this message in the Xcode console:

```
I/O warning : failed to load external entity "https://www.mysite.php"
Document not parsed successfully.
```

I am currently using Xcode Version 10.0.

Anyone has an idea of how to deal with this issue?

Comment: `docNameString==@"https://www.mysite.php";` There are two `=` symbols?

Comment: No. Sorry, this was only a mistype in the post. I fixed it. (There is no mistype in my real code)