# How this post-UrlRequest of Android convert into IOS?

Tags: android, ios, swift, nsurlrequest

The below **Jsoup post request** i am trying to convert into **IOS** but not working like and also set cookies for this so, please any solution for this. i tried to 4-5 days but not success. so, please help me the android code like below:

```
str2 = Jsoup.connect("https://parivahan.gov.in/rcdlstatus/vahan/rcDlHome.xhtml").validateTLSCertificates(false).followRedirects(true)
                    .method(Method.POST).cookies(cookies).
                            referrer("https://parivahan.gov.in/rcdlstatus/?pur_cd=102").
                            header("Content-Type",
                                    "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
                    .header("Host", "parivahan.gov.in")
                    .header("HEADER_ACCEPT", "application/xml, text/xml, */*; q=0.01")
                    .header("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.5")
                    .header("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate, br")
                    .header("X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest")
                    .header("Faces-Request", "partial/ajax")
                    .header("Origin", "https://parivahan.gov.in")
                    .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) " +
                            "AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/64.0.3282.140 " +
                            "Safari/537.36").data("javax.faces.partial.ajax", "true")
                    .data("javax.faces.source", str2).data("javax.faces.partial.execute",
                            "@all").data("javax.faces.partial.render",
                            "form_rcdl:pnl_show form_rcdl:pg_show form_rcdl:rcdl_pnl")
                    .data(str2, str2).data("form_rcdl", "form_rcdl")
                    .data("form_rcdl:tf_reg_no1", str3).data("form_rcdl:tf_reg_no2", vhcasino)
                    .data("javax.faces.ViewState", vhtype).execute().body();
```

In this request many headers and parameter passed so how it perform in ios properly please give any suggestion for it.

**My IOS Code :**

```
      let posturl = URL(string: "https://parivahan.gov.in/rcdlstatus/vahan/rcDlHome.xhtml")
            var postreq = URLRequest(url: posturl!)
            postreq.httpMethod = "POST"
            HTTPCookieStorage.shared.setCookies(self.cookie, for: posturl!, mainDocumentURL: nil)

            postreq.setValue("https://parivahan.gov.in/rcdlstatus/?pur_cd=102", forHTTPHeaderField: "Referer")
            postreq.addValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
            postreq.addValue("application/xml, text/xml, */*; q=0.01", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
            postreq.setValue("parivahan.gov.in", forHTTPHeaderField: "Host")
            postreq.setValue("en-US,en;q=0.5", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept-Language")
            postreq.setValue("gzip, deflate, br", forHTTPHeaderField: "accept-encoding")
            postreq.setValue("XMLHttpRequest", forHTTPHeaderField: "X-Requested-With")
            postreq.setValue("partial/ajax", forHTTPHeaderField: "Faces-Request")
            postreq.setValue("https://parivahan.gov.in/", forHTTPHeaderField: "Origin")
            let userAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) " + "AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/64.0.3282.140" + "Safari/537.36"
            postreq.setValue(userAgent, forHTTPHeaderField: "User-Agent")

            let postparam = ["javax.faces.partial.ajax" : "true" ,
                             "javax.faces.source" : self.str2,
                             "javax.faces.partial.execute" : "@all",
                             "javax.faces.partial.render" : "form_rcdl:pnl_show form_rcdl:pg_show  form_rcdl:rcdl_pnl" ,
                             self.str2 : self.str2 ,
                             "form_rcdl" : "form_rcdl" ,
                             "form_rcdl:tf_reg_no1" : self.regno1,
                             "form_rcdl:tf_reg_no2" : self.regno2,
                             "javax.faces.ViewState": self.vhtype]


            do
            {
                postreq.httpBody = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: postparam, options: [])
            } catch {
                print(error,"error in postreq body")
            }

            print(self.str2)
            print(self.regno1,"reg no1")
            print(self.regno2,"reg no2")


            let posttask = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: postreq, completionHandler: {(data, response, err) in

                if let http = response as? HTTPURLResponse
                {
                    print(http.statusCode)
                }
                if err == nil
                {
                    let con = String(data: data!, encoding: String.Encoding(rawValue: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue))as String?
                    print(con!,"post urlrequest content")
                }
            })

            posttask.resume()
```

Comment: you can use postman to generate swift code for your api

Comment: how use postman for this can you guide me ?

Comment: execute your api as you normally do in postman and after that click on the code option on the right side. From their it will show you a dropdown that in which language you want to generate the code for

Comment: But this is not api it is a URL and get html partial-response in output so how can i go ?

Comment: @jinalrakholiya Can you please share your IOS code with parameter , header and url.

Comment: ok,i edited my answer with ios code.

Comment: @DixitAkabari any solution for this method. stil the problem is not solve. please give any suggestion or solution for it.

Comment: @jinalrakholiya can you send parameter and header you have passed.

Answer (score 0):

You are using Html Parser for Android which will not work on the Swift(IOS) you have to use different plugin I am Not pro in Swift but i found this Plugin hope it helps.

And a Bit Suggestion Swift is based on objective c that is different Language than Android which is using Kotlin and Java we cannot Use Same Plugin

Comment: So, how can i achieve this task ?

Comment: @jinalrakholiya  follow these Links 
1.) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31080818/what-is-the-best-practice-to-parse-html-in-swift

2.) https://github.com/scinfu/SwiftSoup

and Study them

Comment: This is the html parser but i wan't to get response from post request with header and parameter like above. the html parser use in next step after completely get response.