# Extract link from href in Swift

Tags: swift

Suppose I have a html link like this:

```
<a href = "https://mitsui-shopping-park.com/lalaport/koshien/" target="_blank"> https://mitsui-shopping-park.com/lalaport / koshien / </a>
```

I want to extract:

```
<a href = "THIS LINK" target="_blank"> NOT THIS LINK </a>
```

I tried: `someString.replacingOccurrences(of: "<[^>]+>", with: "", options: .regularExpression, range: nil)` but that gives me:

```
<a href = "NOT THIS LINK" target="_blank"> BUT THIS LINK </a>
```

Please help.

Comment: There is some helpful info about parsing HTML here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31080818/what-is-the-best-practice-to-parse-html-in-swift

Comment: The currently accepted answer gives `"href = "https://mitsui-shopping-park.com/lalaport/koshien/"` instead of the actual link, is that the desired output?

Comment: In my case yes this is the desired output.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's one possible solution to grab the value between the `href="` and the closing `"`. This only works with one href in the string.

```
let html = "<a href = \"https://mitsui-shopping-park.com/lalaport/koshien/\" target=\"_blank\"> https://mitsui-shopping-park.com/lalaport / koshien / </a>"

if let hrefRange = html.range(of: "(?:href\\s*=\\s*\")[^\"]*(?:\")", options: .regularExpression) {
    let href = html[hrefRange]
    print(href)
} else {
    print("There is no href")
}
```

Let's break down that regular expression:

First, let's remove the extra `\` needed in the RE to make it a value Swift string. This leaves us with:

```
(?:href\s*=\s*")[^"]*(?:")
```

This has three main parts:

```
(?:href\s*=\s*") - the href, optional space, =, optional space, and opening quote
[^"]* - the actual URL - everything that isn't a quote
(?:") - the close quote
```

The `(?: )` syntax means that the stuff inside won't be part of the returned string.

Comment: how can I get the url(https) itself without href = ? What's the pattern? Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

No need for a regular expression, you could use the [link](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsattributedstring/key/1535719-link) property of an attributed string.

First, let's use [this](https://medium.com/swift2go/swift-how-to-convert-html-using-nsattributedstring-8c6ffeb7046f) extension:

```
extension String{
    func convert2Html() -> NSAttributedString {

        guard let data = data(using: .utf8) else { return NSAttributedString() }

        do {
            let htmlAttrib = NSAttributedString.DocumentType.html
            return try NSAttributedString(data: data,
                                          options: [.documentType : htmlAttrib],
                                          documentAttributes: nil)
        } catch {
            return NSAttributedString()
        }
    }
}
```

to convert this `String`:

```
let html = "<a href = \"https://mitsui-shopping-park.com/lalaport/koshien/\" target=\"_blank\"> https://mitsui-shopping-park.com/lalaport / koshien / </a>"
```

to an `NSAttributedString`:

```
let attrib = html.convert2Html()
```

And then extract the link this way :

```
let link = attrib.attribute(.link, at: 0, effectiveRange: nil)

if let url = link as? NSURL, let href = url.absoluteString {
    print(href)  //https://mitsui-shopping-park.com/lalaport/koshien/
}
```

Comment: using NSAttributedString.DocumentType.html is quite risky, as it can lead to crashes, when outside of main thread, or the document is too large

Answer (score 0):

Use `NSRegularExpression.matches` for the capture group feature of Regular Expression. I always use this handy extension method:

```
extension String {
    func capturedGroups(withRegex pattern: String) -> [String?] {
        var results = [String?]()

        var regex: NSRegularExpression
        do {
            regex = try NSRegularExpression(pattern: pattern, options: [])
        } catch {
            return results
        }

        let matches = regex.matches(in: self, options: [], range: NSRange(location:0, length: self.count))

        guard let match = matches.first else { return results }
        let lastRangeIndex = match.numberOfRanges - 1
        guard lastRangeIndex >= 1 else { return results }

        for i in 0...lastRangeIndex {
            let capturedGroupIndex = match.range(at: i)
            if(capturedGroupIndex.length>0)
            {
                let matchedString = (self as NSString).substring(with: capturedGroupIndex)
                results.append(matchedString)
            }
            else
            {
                results.append(nil)
            }
        }

        return results
    }
}

var html = """
<a href = "https://mitsui-shopping-park.com/lalaport/koshien/" target="_blank"> https://mitsui-shopping-park.com/lalaport / koshien / </a>
"""
print(html.capturedGroups(withRegex: "href\\s*=\\s*\"([^\"]+)\"")[1])
```

Comment: Why an array of optional strings?

Comment: I remember I copied this from a SO post and put it in my project codebase and keep using it. LOL never thought about that. Yes that makes no sense.