# How to get text and trim it from a link?

Tags: swift

Suppose I have:

```
"<p>I need <a href='www.alink.com'> www.alink.com / x /y </a>, along with this. </p>"
```

I want to get the text : `I need www.alink.com/x/y, along with this.`

I tried removing html by:

```
someString?.replacingOccurrences(of: "<[^>]+>", with: "", options: .regularExpression, range: nil)
```

then I get: `I need www.alink.com / x / y, along with this.`

I need the link text without the space, how can I do that?

Comment: How is this different from the question you asked 2 hours ago? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56051722/extract-link-from-href-in-swift

Comment: This got text back and front, which I am struggling to concatenate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to replace the whitespace and the next coming character with only the character.

```
ans="Hello i am goutham /t /n /m"
ans.replace(" /", "/")
```

which gives:

```
'Hello i am goutham/t/n/m'
```