# Extract multiple elements out of HTML String in Swift

Tags: html, swift, string, extract

I have a string containing some HTML content including multiple elements that match the following scheme:

```
<a data-pdf-link="/path/to/the/file.pdf" class="tocPdfContainer" href="#" > Some title <i class="fa fa-download"></i></a>
```

Now I want to get an array which contains all of the HTML-String's `<a>`-Elements so I can extract each's PDF link and title.  How can I do that?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31080818/what-is-the-best-practice-to-parse-html-in-swift. Hope this helps!!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the best practice to parse html in swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31080818/what-is-the-best-practice-to-parse-html-in-swift)

Comment: Thanks, it works fine with SwiftSoup!