# how to get all the headings in a array?

Tags: ios, swift

I have the following array

```
["<h1>Test</h1><h2>Test2</h2>", "<h3>Hello, playground</h3>Testing", "<h3>Test</h3>", "<h2>Main Takeaway</h2>"]
```

I want to get all the values between `<h3>` and `</h3>` as well as `<h2>` and `</h2>`. So I want to create an array with the following values

```
Hello, playground,
Test
Main Takeaway
```

How do I do that?

Comment: What if you have h2 and h3 on the same index? In the result, should it be two values, or one?

Comment: There will never be an h2 and h3 in an entry. There will either be one h2 or one h3

Comment: I tried using the .components function, but that didn't work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/31080818/1974224

Comment: No its not a duplicate. You should read the question more carefully.

Comment: `".*(<h[23]>)(.*)(</h[23]>).*"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a regular expression to find and replace the values within the h2/h3 tags

```
let array = ["<h1>Test</h1><h2>Test2</h2>", "<h3>Hello, playground</h3>Testing", "<h3>Test</h3>", "<h2>Main Takeaway</h2>"]

let values = array.map { $0.replacingOccurrences(of: #".*(<h2>|<h3>)(.*)(</h2>|</h3>).*"#, with: "$2", options: .regularExpression) }
```

Comment: This will return the whole string if there are no `h2/h3` tags, maybe an empty string would've been a better candidate. Also, in case there are multiple tags within the same string, then this will match only one of them. Another corner case is with strings like `<h2>text</h3>`, the regex will match these invalid combinations too.