# how to get particular tag for html value in swift

Tags: html, swift

I have this set of html

```
<div class="_57-o acbk" data-store="{&quot;object_id&quot;:254863256822548}" id="u_0_3_XB" data-sigil="photo-stage marea">

 <img src="https://scontent.fdel10-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t39.30808-6/274092727_254863253489215_7220866489517235931_n.jpg?stp=cp0_dst-jpg_e15_fr_q65&amp;_nc_cat=107&amp;ccb=1-5&amp;_nc_sid=dd9801&amp;_nc_ohc=EAKHwJL9zzcAX9HXKnn&amp;_nc_ht=scontent.fdel10-1.fna&amp;oh=00_AT-T0elfrrjiMuDTzi2DO2nIS7zzjAjQkeROOj04Lv_v1A&amp;oe=6220A6D4" width="414" height="232" class="img" data-store="{&quot;imgsrc&quot;:&quot;https:\/\/scontent.fdel10-1.fna.fbcdn.net\/v\/t39.30808-6\/274092727_254863253489215_7220866489517235931_n.jpg?stp=cp0_dst-jpg_e15_fr_q65&amp;_nc_cat=107&amp;ccb=1-5&amp;_nc_sid=dd9801&amp;_nc_ohc=EAKHwJL9zzcAX9HXKnn&amp;_nc_ht=scontent.fdel10-1.fna&amp;oh=00_AT-T0elfrrjiMuDTzi2DO2nIS7zzjAjQkeROOj04Lv_v1A&amp;oe=6220A6D4&quot;}" alt="May be an image of 4 people and text" data-sigil="photo-image" data-store-id="0">
```

how to get the url inside the imgsrc tag

Comment: I'm sorry but it is not too clear what you want ? From the above html tag what is it that you want exactly ? The url inside the img src ?

Answer (score 1):

The most robust solution is to use a HTML parser (e.g. [Hpple](https://github.com/topfunky/hpple) or [NDHpple](https://github.com/ndavon/NDHpple) or [others](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31081271/1271826)).

You can get pretty close just using regular expressions (a.k.a. “regex”).

For example, a simple implementation with look ahead/behind expressions might be:

```swift
if let range = string.range(of: #"(?<=<img src\s?=\s?")[^"]*(?=".*>)"#, options: [.regularExpression, .caseInsensitive]) {
    print(string[range])
}
```

A slightly more robust implementation, using capture groups, would be:

```swift
let pattern = #"<img\b.*\bsrc\s*=\s*"([^"]+)".*>"#
let regex = try! NSRegularExpression(pattern: pattern, options: .caseInsensitive)

let nsRange = NSRange(string.startIndex..., in: string)
regex.enumerateMatches(in: string, range: nsRange) { result, _, _ in
    if let range = (result?.range(at: 1)).flatMap({ Range($0, in: string) }) {
        print(string[range])
    }
}
```

The basic idea in both is to find the substring within the quotation marks between the `<img src="` and the closing `"` and subsequent `>`. See the `NSRegularExpression` [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsregularexpression) for details about regex patterns.

But, strictly speaking, neither regex approach is quite correct, as they make many assumptions about the nature of the HTML. Regex simply is not a replacement for a proper HTML parser. See [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags).

If this is just a quick-and-dirty exercise, the regex will get you pretty close, but if you really want robust parsing of image URLs, you really should use one of the aforementioned HTML [parsers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31081271/1271826).